# SQL unite two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

How to unite sku_i and sku_o column, so the null can be filled with the data beside it (sku_i or sku_o)? I assure you that if sku_i is null then sku_o has a value.

[image: table]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctAQ5.png

Comment: Would you be so kind to provide sample data and desired output? It looks like you need COALESCE()

Comment: What **exactly** do you want to achieve? What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `COALESCE`:

```sql
SELECT *, COALESCE(sku_i, sku_o) AS sku
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use coalesce

```
SELECT coalesce(sku_i,sku_o) AS new_name FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `coalesce(sku_i,sku_o)`. This will select first non null value. If `sku_i` is null then it will select `sku_o` otherwise it will select `sku_1`.

```
select id, trans_id, qty, trans_date, coalesce(sku_i,sku_o) from yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the ifnull feature in case one is unknownly poptulated.

`ifnull(sku_i,sku_o)`

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_ifnull.asp

Comment: COALESCE is better as it used normally in all databases.